# How to show transpiled code in VS Code when debugging original (source-mapped) TS source?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, source-maps, vscode-debugger

When I'm debugging in VS Code and seeing the original TS source of a transpiled app, how can I view the transpiled code that's actually being debugged?

I'm asking because I'm trying to troubleshoot a problem related to imports/exports/Webpack not working correctly inside some Jest tests. I'd like to set a breakpoint in the original source, and while VS Code is stopped at the breakpoint I'd like to view (and ideally, single-step through) the actual transpiled JS for the next original-source line. How?

Ideally I'd be able to debug that code in the VS Code debugger. I'd settle for simply viewing the transpiled code, but I'm not even sure where the transpiled code lives on disk. It's not my code, it's a monorepo library written in TS with a complex build process, so I have no idea where the transpiled code is and given that Jest is executing the code I'm not even sure if the transpiled code is persisted to disk at all!

Comment: does this help https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_50#_javascript-debugging see paragraph `Step through missing code`

Comment: I don't think so. In my case the original source isn't missing. I simply want to temporarily ignore it in the middle of a debug session so that I can view the transpiled code.

Comment: in case the `.ts` files are missing they allow to step through the compiled code, they can make this optional, maybe create an issue for the JavaScript-Debugger. Something like stepping through the assembler instructions if you debug a C++ program.

Comment: I'm also trying to find the answer to this. The TS code that's displayed in the debugger doesn't evaluate correctly. If I "watch" the variable, it evaluates to a different value. But the JS file seems to be hidden / inaccessible so I can't see HOW it's evaluating.